# Dialog with statusbar

Tags: c++, qt, qmainwindow, qdialog

I need to use a dialog with a statusbar. I don't know how can I use it in `QDialog` so I use `QMainWindow`. But `QMainWindow` doesn't have `exec()` function and `show()` function works asynchronously.

I use `QtDesigner` and I did not understand how can I add statusbar using it. I also want to see status tips of widnow's widgets in this statusbar.

Comment: Why you can't use statusbar in `QDialog`? `QDialog` is `QWidget`. Same as `QMainWindow`. Could you describe a final result, that you want to achieve?

Comment: As a side note/rant: modal dialogs which block the GUI are often bad UI design. User might often want to check some things from the main application, while a dialog is open, and it's really annoying to close the dialog to check it, perhaps copy-paste something elsewhere so it can be looked at while the dialog is open, then re-open the dialog. Especially annoying with wizard-type multi-page dialogs, where you might have filled many pages and then need to re-do it all. So, if there is another way, use that, for better UX. Sometimes just make the dialog non-modal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make your own dialog window modal with [`QWidget::setWindowModality`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qwidget.html#windowModality-prop), probably [`ApplicationModal` or `WindowModal`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qt.html#WindowModality-enum), for example in its constructor. Additionally, you probably want to set [window flags for dialog](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qt.html#WindowType-enum), so you can give you dialog a parent. So, add these to your dialog mainwindow constructor:

```
setWindowModality(Qt::ApplicationModal);
setWindowFlags(Qt::Dialog);
```

That way it will open as independent window even with parent, block out rest of your GUI until closed, prevent that from getting user input events. This should behave the same as if you used [`QDialog::open`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qdialog.html#open).

To catch the user closing the dialog, you should probably add the same [signals as used by `QDialog`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qdialog.html#signals) to it, and emit them as appropriate. That way you can your custom dialog and `QDialog` interchangeably, and also your code is easier to understand (this is called *static polymorphism*, giving semantically unrelated but functionally equivalent things same names).

---

Here's some example code, first constructor of DialogWindow custom class:

```
DialogWindow ::DialogWindow (QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    setWindowFlags(Qt::Dialog);
    setWindowModality(Qt::ApplicationModal);
    setCentralWidget(new QLabel("Dialog")); // show some content
}
```

And then `main` function to use it:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QPushButton w("Open the Dialog"); // the "main window" of the whole application
    DialogWindow *dialog = new DialogWindow (&w);
    QObject::connect(&w, SIGNAL(clicked()), dialog, SLOT(show()));
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: @Ufx Added the relevant code snippets that worked for me

Comment: My QMainWindow derived class is not the "main window" of the whole application. I am not sure that I did correct but it does not work for me. Window showed asynchronously.

Comment: @Ufx In my example, the QPushButton is the "main window", and I renamed the dialog window class to "DialogWindow" to make it clearer. But yes, it is asynchronous, same as if you used `QDialog::open`. So you need to handle the result of the dialog in a separate slot, there's a paragraph about that in the answer.

Comment: It works. Thanks. But why there is possible to add statusbar using QtDesigner for QMainWindow and there is not possible to add it for QDialog?

Comment: @Ufx The status bar of `QMainWindow` is its feature, convenience basically. You can add a `QStatusBar` anywhere in any Qt widget, you just have to do it yourself, like shown in the other answer. `QMainWindow` doesn't do any "magic", it just has similar code built in. And the Designer has some hard-coded features for `QMainWindow`, so creating normal desktop applicatons with it is easier and quicker.

Answer (score 3):

Create dialog with `QVBoxLayout` for example.

Place all widget which you need and add `QStatusBar` on bottom.

In main.cpp:

```
QDialog dlg;
QLayout *l = new QVBoxLayout(&dlg);
QLabel *lbl = new QLabel("text");
QPushButton *bb = new QPushButton("text");
l->addWidget(bb);
l->addWidget(lbl);
QStatusBar *b = new QStatusBar;
l->addWidget(b);
b->showMessage("text");
l->setMargin(0);
l->setSpacing(0);
dlg.show();
```

Update: for status tips you should create `QDialog` subclass:

dia.h:

```
#ifndef DIA_H
#define DIA_H

#include <QDialog>
 #include <QStatusBar>
 #include <QLayout>
 #include <QApplication>
 #include <QTextEdit>
 #include <QStatusTipEvent>
 #include <QPushButton>

 class Dia : public QDialog {
 public:
    Dia() : QDialog()
    {
        QVBoxLayout *l = new QVBoxLayout(this);
        QTextEdit *te = new QTextEdit;
        te->setStatusTip("this is TextEdit");
        l->addWidget(te);
        QPushButton *bb = new QPushButton("tezt");
        bb->setStatusTip("this is button");
        l->addWidget(bb);
        bar = new QStatusBar;
        l->addWidget(bar);
        l->setMargin(0);
        l->setSpacing(0);
    }
 private:
    QStatusBar *bar;
 protected:
    bool event(QEvent *e)
    {
        if(e->type()==QEvent::StatusTip)
        {
            QStatusTipEvent *ev = (QStatusTipEvent*)e;
            bar->showMessage(ev->tip());
            return true;
        }
        return QDialog::event(e);
    }
 };
#endif // DIA_H
```

Using:

```
#include "dia.h"
//...    
Dia dlg;
dlg.show();
```

Comment: This works but how can I paint status tips when cursor is under widgets? And is there possible to make this using QtDesigner?

Comment: @Ufx, you did not mention the status texts in your question. Please extend your question so that everybody knows what functionality you need.

Comment: @Ufx see my update please, status tips are little more complicated. I added a few widgets and setStatusTip to every widget and did code more readable.